# ListPlot: Adding Line with Epilog to automatic GridLines - adjusting Style

Tags: plotting, style, grid-lines

I want to draw ListPlots with automatic GridLines and add a custom line.

My solution is to use the Epilog option. To make sure that the automatic GridLines and my custom line have the same style, I create a style Directive and use the GridLinesStyle option. Here is an example:

```
defGrSty = Directive[{Thickness[0.0002], Black, Opacity[1.0]}];
defEp = {defGrSty, InfiniteLine[{{0, 5}, {2, 5}}]};
data = {{1, -12}, {2, 3}, {3, 10}, {4, 20}, {5, 42}};

ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, GridLinesStyle -> defGrSty, 
GridLines -> Automatic, Epilog -> defEp]
```

My problem is, that the manual added line looks different. It does not look black, but gray. The cause could be, that the opacity of this line is decreased at the edges.

Comment: Are you working with Magnification different that 100%? Because for 100% it's ok but for e.g. 110% is looks strange.

Comment: Which magnification do you mean? The magnification of the window? With the following modified code I have the same problems: `defGrSty = 
  Directive[{Thickness[0.0002], Black, Opacity[1.0], 
    Magnification -> 1}];
defEp = {defGrSty, Magnification -> 1, InfiniteLine[{{0, 5}, {2, 5}}]};
data = {{1, -12}, {2, 3}, {3, 10}, {4, 20}, {5, 42}};
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, GridLinesStyle -> defGrSty, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, Epilog -> defEp], Magnification -> 1]` I am using Mathematica 10.1 .

Comment: Yes, Notebook, what is on the bottom right corner.

Comment: I have set it 100% and the problem remains. It seems, that the appearance of this line depends on the Mathematica version or installation. I use version 10.1.0.0 for Linux

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, for [certain values](http://i.imgur.com/MMMDOzr.png) of the `Thickness`, the gridlines and the line have the same apparent style and for others they do not.

Comment: I guess, that the problem appears on some versions of Mathematica for every `Thickness`, but for increasing thickness the difference gets less noticeable. It looks like the opacity gets decreased in a section at the edge. At high thickness this section seems to get very small. But even there a small difference is visible. If you use `Thickness[0.0001 #]` instead of `Thickness[0.001 #]` in your example, every line looks strange.

Comment: So I don't think this has anything to do with `Epilog`, but with the differences in how `Style` is applied to gridlines versus other lines.  I can modify the question to get straight to this point if you don't mind

Comment: This is an imperfection of rendering in the notebook. When I export the resulting graphic to a pdf, the lines all look identical.

Comment: @JasonB what you're observing with different thicknesses is somewhat reminiscent of rounding off to an integer amount of printer points. I get similar problems when using `FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1.8]` in my plots, when preparing figures for publication and in the notebook it seems as though the different sides of the frame have different thicknesses, but after exporting to a vector format everything is fine.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, what kind of vector format?  Look at the result of [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/twxjqN4P) code - it does appear to round the `Thickness` values for `GridLinesStyle`

Comment: @JasonB I usually export to pdf. After running your code and adding a line `Export["Z:/test.pdf", Grid@%]` the lines in each row are indistinguishable and seem to be consistent with the thicknesses defined.

Comment: I get the same thing - but if you use a bitmap format like .png, then they look the same as in the notebook.  Seems buggy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you run your code,

```
defGrSty = Directive[{Thickness[0.0002], Black, Opacity[1.0]}];
defEp = {defGrSty, InfiniteLine[{{0, 5}, {2, 5}}]};
data = {{1, -12}, {2, 3}, {3, 10}, {4, 20}, {5, 42}};

plot = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, GridLinesStyle -> defGrSty, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, Epilog -> defEp]
```

and it does not display the gridlines and the added line in the same style,

[image]

You have a couple options.  If you want to use the output elsewhere, just export it to PDF, and it displays just fine

```
Export["temp/plot.pdf", plot]
```

[image]

Or, if you want it to display in the notebook properly, you can go through this rigmarole

```
grdlns = AbsoluteOptions[plot, GridLines][[1, 2, All, All, 1]];
AppendTo[grdlns[[2]], 5.];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, GridLines -> glns, 
 GridLinesStyle -> defGrSty]
```

[image]

At the heart of the matter, it seems to do some kind of rounding for the values of `Thickness` that are given to `GridLinesStyle`.  Here, for each pair the one on the left is a `Line` and the one on the right is a `GridLine`, both with the same style,

```
opts = {ImageSize -> {50, 100}, AspectRatio -> 2, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> False};
img = Grid[{GraphicsRow /@ ((defGrSty = 
         Directive[{Thickness[#], Black, Opacity[1.0]}];
        {Graphics[{Directive[defGrSty], Line[{{0, -2}, {0, 2}}]}, 
          opts],
         Plot[Null, {x, -2, 2}, GridLines -> {{0}, None}, 
          GridLinesStyle -> defGrSty, Evaluate@opts]}) & /@ {0.001, 
       0.002, 0.01, 0.02, .03, 0.04})}]
```

[image]

But again, it goes away if you export to pdf, as LLlAMnYP pointed out.

Comment: Thank you very much for these two solutions and the extensive investigation of the causes.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that the custom grid line has the same style by adding it to the `GridLines` specification.  Then it will be drawn with all the other grid lines.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, GridLinesStyle -> defGrSty,
 GridLines -> {Automatic, Append[5]@Range[-10, 40, 10]}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Setting the horizontal `GridLines` manually is a possible solution. I don't want to use it. I have many plots with differing y-axis ticks. Thus I want to use the automatic generated `GridLines` with one manually added line, which everytime is needed. Thank you.